# How do you use "si" and "hubiera" ("If" and "had")

Tags: gramática

I am studying Spanish with the Michel Thomas Method.

It states that in Spanish, `"Had"` is `"había"`:

```
Lo había comprado. / I had bought it.
```

If using `"if"`,  `"Had"` becomes `"hubiera"` as this expresses an element of doubt in the word `"had"`:

```
Si lo hubiera sabido, lo habría hecho./ If I had known it, I would have done it.

si hubiera estado allí anoche / if I had been there last night
```

Later on, it gives this example:

```
Si tuviera el tiempo lo haría. / If I had the time, I would do it.
```

I am confused: Why is there no `hubiera` in this last example? I assume `tener (have)` has been modified into `tuviera` to express doubt, but why isn't `hubiera` used?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, hubiera goes into tuviera. And that's it. I don't know if this method is helping you but I don't think direct translation is a good idea when learning languages and subjunctive tenses are kind of dificult to translate directly so you're going to have a rough time with it

Comment: @Matias Andina `hubiera goes into tuviera` - What do you mean? Also, what's the best way to learn without translating into English (as I only fluently understand English)?

Comment: What I mean is that you have to use tuviera instead of hubiera. You're trying to say another thing so you do not need "hubiera" as auxiliar verb. I would use grammatical constructions given by the spanish language. Look for subjunctive tenses in spanish, they are constructed according to rules, it's not random.

Comment: @MatiasAndina If you are talking about a possession (e.g. car, time) you use `tuviera` (because that comes from `tener` which translates to possession) but if you had something that is not a possession (like a being somewhere or knowing something), you use `hubiera`? Is that correct? Is that the rule? Also `You're trying to say another thing so you do not need "hubiera"` "Another thing" - I don't quite follow what you mean.

Comment: You can "tener" A LOT of things (hunger, anger, dissapointment, etc) It does not have to be a real object but yes, if you have/would have a real object then you tienes/tendría o tuviera. Since hubiera is the auxiliar verb (just as have is used for present perfect as auxiliar verb) it is needed for some verbs that use "hubiera". Since tener is not one of the verbs that need tuviera (and so "you are trying to say another thing") you don't need it. Hubiera works for subjunctive as auxiliar conjugation of haber, but you also have "haya" and so on check https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modo_subjuntivo

Comment: @MatiasAndina Please post as answer so I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to write my comments as an answer.

First, I would say that your assumption is correct, `hubiera` goes into `tuviera`. And that's it.

On a personal remark, I don't know if this method is helping you but I don't think direct translation is a good idea when learning languages. In particular, subjunctive tenses are kind of dificult to translate directly so you're going to have a rough time with it. I would look for subjunctive tenses in spanish, they are constructed according to rules, it's not random.

What I mean is that you have to use `tuviera` instead of `hubiera` because you're trying to say "another thing" so you do not need `haber` as auxiliar verb.

You can "tener" A LOT of things (hunger, anger, dissapointment, etc). It does not have to be a real object but yes, if you have/would have a real object then you tienes/tendría o tuviera. Since `hubiera` is working as the auxiliar verb (just as have is used for present perfect as auxiliar verb) it is needed for some verbs that use "hubiera". Since `tener` is not one of the verbs that need auxiliar, you can use `tuviera` (and this is what I mean when I said "you are trying to say another thing") `Hubiera` works for subjunctive as auxiliar conjugation of `haber`, but you also have `haya` and so on check [es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modo_subjuntivo](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modo_subjuntivo)

Also, keep in mind that subjunctive mode is one of the last things that native people learn during elementary school and it is seldom used correctly because of its difficulty.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need "hubiera" because you don't need an auxiliary verb. To have time--in Spanish--idiomatically uses "tener" because in a way you do *possess* time. So what you do is put tener in the imperfect subjunctive, just as you put haber in the imperfect subjunctive in the other sentence.

Comment: So if you possess something (e.g. time), you use `tuviera` (because that comes from `tener` which translates to possession) but if you had something that is not a possession (like a being somewhere or knowing something), you use `hubiera`? Is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly, think of haber as a helping verb. It will only be used in conjunction with another main verb. So in one of your examples "lo había comprado" you use haber to accompany the past participle of "comprar". Comprar is the main verb and haber is helping, it doesn't necessarily have meaning in and of itself.

Comment: So if you use a noun, you use tuviera. But for a verb you use hubiera? Is that correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**had** becomes **hubiera/hubiese/tuviera/tuviese** when dealing with conditional sentences.
In this case, to form the Third Conditional, we use *if + past perfect* where the past perfect is not translated as *había* for the word *had* but *hubiera/hubiese/tuviera/tuviese.*

Remember that *have = haber/tener*. The examples uses *tuviera* because there's first person talking there. — *Si (yo) tuviera* (...) —

If we say — *Si hubiera el tiempo, lo haría —*, it makes sense but it's not 100% for clear what we're talking about. That expression is used but not often.

The same if we put — *Si yo hubiera el tiempo, lo haría* —, it's wrong because its lack of coherence, hence we put *had = tuviera* to make it clear. — *Si yo tuviera el tiempo, lo haría.* —

Comment: so basically haber/tener differentiate between "having" as a possession and "having" as a concept (and in Spanish time is a possession)? Is that correct?